# Rails test model instance method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, rspec2

So new to testing and hope you can advise.

I have a simple model:

```
class Checkout < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates.........  

  def number_of_days
    (checkout - checkin).to_i
  end

end
```

I would like to test that 'number_of_days' method returns the correct value. I have tried mock_model and various other ways to stub the class but just cant get it working.

Here is my lastest attempt which still does not work:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe Checkout do

  it "should calculate the number of days" do
    checkout = mock_model(Checkout, 
          checkin: 2.days.from_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 
          checkout: 4.days.from_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
          )
    expect(checkout.number_of_days).to eq(2)
  end

end
```

Error for the above test is "ouble "Checkout_1001" received unexpected message :number_of_days with (no args)"

So Im obviously still on the wrong path.

Can you advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create any mock. Just create an instance of the object values you are giving to the mock and assert the returned value of the number_of_days method.

```
describe Checkout do

  it "should calculate the number of days" do
    checkout = Checkout.new( 
          checkin: 2.days.from_now.strftime('%Y-%m/%d'), 
          checkout: 4.days.from_now.strftime('%Y-%m/%d')
          )
    checkout.number_of_days.should eq(2)
  end

end
```

Comment: I had a small typo and bang it works :-). I thought as I had validations it would throw errors. Nice TY very much

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just make a new instance object?

```
checkout = Checkout.new(
  checkin: 2.days.from_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 
  checkout: 4.days.from_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  )
```